# Angular Material dynamic form control focus with HTMLElement reference

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I use [ng-dynamic-forms](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms) in my angular material application. I have an issue where I cannot seem to set focus on my dynamic controls manually. I found some old documentation that uses a method to grab the raw HTMLElement reference:

```
const typeInput: HTMLElement = this._dynamicFormComponentService.getFormControlRef("Name").location.nativeElement;
```

This appears to work for me. The object it gets back appears to be correct:

[image: HTML element]

That is in fact the HTMLElement for the control I want to focus, but when I call `typeInput.focus()`, nothing happens. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: could you also share _dynamicFormComponentService implementation and your view as well?

Comment: @Laminoo Lawrance That service is written in the dynamic forms package I linked above. Here is the implementation in that repo https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms/blob/master/projects/ng-dynamic-forms/core/src/lib/service/dynamic-form-component.service.ts